# How to write yml file using python pyml package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyml

i want create yml file using python dictionary how to make dictionary format that i can get below format yml file

```
responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: Hey! How are you?
    buttons:
    - title: "good"
      payload: "/greet"
    - title: "bad"
      payload: "/health"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package to convert to `dict`
https://github.com/Infinidat/munch

```
pip3 install munch
```

convert to dict

```
import yaml
from munch import Munch
mydict = yaml.safe_load("""
responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: Hey! How are you?
    buttons:
    - title: "good"
      payload: "/greet"
    - title: "bad"
      payload: "/health"
""")
print(mydict)
```

convert dict to yaml

```
with open('output.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(mydict, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get this yml template using python:

It has to be generating a `UUID` for a file and the file generated should have this `yml template`:

```
import uuid
print(uuid.uuid1())
u = str(uuid.uuid1())
u
open(u+".yml", "a+")
```

YML template format:

```
- id: 7049e3ec-b822-4fdf-a4ac-18190f9b66d1
  name: Powerkatz (Staged)
  description: Use Invoke-Mimikatz
  tactic: credential-access
  technique:
    attack_id: T1003.001
    name: "OS Credential Dumping: LSASS Memory"
  privilege: Elevated
  platforms:
    windows:
      psh:
        command: |
          Import-Module .\invoke-mimi.ps1;
          Invoke-Mimikatz -DumpCreds
        parsers:
          plugins.stockpile.app.parsers.katz:
          - source: domain.user.name
            edge: has_password
            target: domain.user.password
          - source: domain.user.name
            edge: has_hash
            target: domain.user.ntlm
          - source: domain.user.name
            edge: has_hash
            target: domain.user.sha1
        payloads:
        - invoke-mimi.ps1
```